# Split Array Into Parts - Get all Unique Items - GoogleSQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm looking to take a String-Array field in Google SQL and transpose it to show all in one column. From there I can take all unique/distinct items from it.

the image above is a sample of what I am trying
[image]

I can't get the string array to split out into resulting rows.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it using `unnest`, assuming columnB is holding the array:

```
select numbers 
from yourtable t
cross join unnest(t.ColumnB) numbers
```

and for distinct :

```
select distinct numbers 
from yourtable t
cross join unnest(t.ColumnB) numbers
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didnt work for me - What does arr(numbers) do?

Comment: its just alias for unnest statement , what do you mean by "it didn't work"?

Comment: Amazing! That worked for me, appreciate the help! The alias was what was catching me I get now the reference back to the cross_joined table

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as answer (as it is too long for comments) - just to point that usually users using too verbose syntax with unnest function. For example - instead of using  `unnest(t.ColumnB)` one can use either `unnest(ColumnB)` or just `t.ColumnB` as in examples below

```
select number
from your_table t, t.ColumnB number
```

and

```
select distinct number
from your_table t, t.ColumnB number
```

I personally prefer this shortcut version of using unnest - so wanted to share - while obviously this is a personal preferences type of things